# Выйти по ширине за пределы wrapper

Tags: html, css

Есть обертка (wrapper) width: 1024px, блок выровнен по центру. Весь контент находится в нем.
Но есть другой блок, бэкграунд которого должен быть во всей ширине экрана, то есть выходить за пределы 1024px, но текст должен находится на таком же уровне, что и контент в обертке. Только бекграунд на всю ширину экрана. Возможно, не совсем ясно выразился,посему прикрепил изображение.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Как правильно будет сделать в CSS?
Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рекомендую Вам в таких случаях использовать другую структуру страницы:

```
<div class="section1">
   <div class="inner-wrap">
         тут контент
   </div>
</div>
<div class="section2">
   <div class="inner-wrap">
         тут контент
   </div>
</div>
<div class="section3">
   <div class="inner-wrap">
         тут контент
   </div>
</div>
```

То есть div с класами section обертки на всю ширину, а inner-wrap сделайте 1024px

Вариант 2: 
можно использовать псевдоелементы after и before с абсолютным позиционирование для задания фонового изображения.

Comment: спасибо. помогли